# ModelValidationException was unhandled by usercode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in need to use two models in single view page and hence used below method whereas Test is ViewModel class. I am getting the following error:

> EntityType 'parentmodel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   pmodel: EntityType: EntitySet 'pmodel' is based on type 'parentmodel' that has no keys defined.

How do resolve this?

```
public class parentmodel
{
    [Key]
    public Test test{get;set;}
    public Employee employee{get;set;}
}
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public string hdNoOfColumns { get; set; }
    public string hdNoOfRows { get; set; }
}
[Table("allocdetails",Schema="public")]
public class EmployeeAllocation
{
    [Key]
    public DateTime allocdate { get; set; }
    public string roomno { get; set; }
    public string groupname {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: `parentmodel` is a view model, not a data model. Remove the `[Key]` attribute and put in a separate folder.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I am getting the same error even after removing Key attribute. Test class is also view model. Key attribute should be there in Test class? and can you please clarify on "put in a separate folder". Do you mean shared/Viewmodel folder?

Comment: If `Test` is also a view model, then it should not have a `[Key]` attribute (you don't want EF's Code First creating a table for them). Create a separate folder (say ViewModels for them)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Getting the same error even after put the Models in a separate folder.